# Delete Excel data connection that does not want to delete

Tags: excel, vba, database-connection

It is very strange I cannot delete a data connection. It return error each time I try to delete and If I use VBA to delete all connection then all connection except this one is deleted!

Anyone have an idea on how to delete this bugged data connection? I do not want to start a fresh new Excel file and redo all the tabs, formats and connections!

Renaming file, changing extension did not help.

[image: This is the data connection]

[image: The second picture is the error when I try to delete]

[image: The third picture is when I want to edit/modify the connection but I cannot edit anything except name and command]

EDI: Anyone here able to explain this error and how to correct it? Today I discovered other files with same issue and the only way I found to recover is to make a new file and start from scratch...

Comment: I'd take a backup of your workbook before doing what I am about to suggest, but, you could always dive into the XML behind the workbook and try and delete it that way.

Comment: yeah it removed the connection but still got error from that file when I update other connection... look like the file is corrupt :( testing all connection on a fresh file work like a charm but still have to link and format evrything. stupid bug!

Comment: Anyone here able to explain this error and how to correct it? Today I discovered other files with same issue and the only way I found to recover is to make a new file and start from scratch...